# Script run by Jenkins writing to build workspace

Tags: jenkins

**Scenario:** I have a script that generates some files that `Jenkins` needs to SCP over to various destination hosts using [`Publish Over SSH Plugin`](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin). In the case of using a specialized plugin, such as Maven, the resulting artifacts are by default placed in the build workspace directory but this is a script that resides in the Jenkens server file system and it dumps files wherever its input configuration tells it. I was hoping that I could supply the absolute path to the Jenkins SSH job but that didn't work -- apparently, its scope of accessibility is the particular build's workspace. So while the job *GenerateFiles* successfully dumps proper files in a static location (e.g. /var/local/dump), the job *SendFilesOver* in the downstream can't access those files.

**Question:** How can I specify the parameter in *GenerateFiles* where to dump the files in ${JENKINS_WORKSPACE}/${THIS_BUILD} so that *SendFilesOver* can copy it from there (using "Copy artifacts from another project") to its own workspace so that it can SCP it over to the destination?

Comment: How are you `GenerateFiles` generating files?

Comment: Python script that takes in parameters

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping you are doing all this by using `shell scripting`. So After generating all files, ie. to a custom static location, set a variable that's gonna point to this location. Now using that path, copy that directory/file(s) to your build workspace so that downstream jobs will access those files. I think you can fetch the current workspace by using `$WORKSPACE` env var of Jenkins. Hope this helps.

Comment: you can do the same in python scripting also.